# How do we get notification when app is installed on android

Tags: android

I need to get a notification once the app is intalled on android device. Based on the status that app is installed or not then i need to update something. Please help me on this.

Thanks
KIRAN

Comment: Did my answer help you? You should accept if it did, or clarify what the question is if it didn't.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the intent  "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" is broadcasted when a new app is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently come across this problem. Here is how it's working for me. I am targeting API level 30. I have created a broadcast receiver that notifies me when an app is installed or uninstalled on the device.

Following is my receiver tag inside the Application tag in AndroidManifest.xml. I didn't find PACKAGE_ADDED action working for me.

```
<receiver android:name="com.vikasmane.appdatasdk.PackageChangeReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Queries tag required to receive PACKAGE_CHANGED. This can be added under the manifest tag

```
 <queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

The PackageChangeReceiver receives PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED/PACKAGE_CHANGED. The package name can be retrieved using

```
 val packageName = intent?.data?.encodedSchemeSpecificPart
```

Here is my Broadcast receiver

```
class PackageChangeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    // fetching package names from extras
    val packageName = intent?.data?.encodedSchemeSpecificPart
    when (intent?.action) {
        Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED -> Toast.makeText(
            context, 
            "${packageName.toString()} uninstalled",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
        Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED -> Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "${packageName.toString()} installed",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
}
```

You can find this implementation in my repo https://github.com/vikasvmane/Launcher for reference.